# WKWebView play YouTube video stops camera and microphone input

Tags: ios, swift, video, youtube, wkwebview

I am creating an iOS native app with Swift.

The app has a single UIView, which contains the top 50% with WKWebVeiw, which loads YouTube video URL (Also I tried Google's youtube_ios_player_helper YTPlayerView, which basically is a WKWebView as well)

In the bottom half of UIView I embedded AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, which shows what is in front of my iPhone camera.

Also at the same time I initialised SFSpeechRecognizer to capture the user's voice.

The AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and SFSpeechRecognizer are working fine before I press the YouTube "Play" button in my WKWebView

However, once I press YouTube "Play" button in WKWebView (The YouTube video start playing), AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer freezes, and SFSpeechRecognizer stopes working.

At the following is how I create the WKWebView to load YouTube video:

```
        var youTubePlayerWebView: WKWebView! = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: videoplayerX, y: videoplayerY, width: videoplayerWidth, height: videoplayerHeight))
        youTubePlayerWebView.load(URLRequest(url: videoUrl))
        self.view.addSubview(youTubePlayerWebView)
```

At the following is how I create camera

```
        self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session!)
        self.previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.previewLayer?.connection!.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        self.previewLayer?.frame = self.cameraPreview.bounds
        self.cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer!)
        self.session?.startRunning()
```

At the following is how I monitor the user's voice:

```
    guard let node = audioEngine?.inputNode else { return }
    let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat (forBus: 0)
    node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
        self.request.append (buffer)
    }
    audioEngine?.prepare ()
    do {
        try audioEngine?.start()
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.default)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
    } catch {
        return print (error)
    }
    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { result, error in
        if let result = result {
           //....voice recognition logic
```

I need a way to allow my camera and microphone continue working while WKWebView is playing YouTube video.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, here goes the answer:
When initialise the session for AVCaptureSession for camera video capturing, I need to set:

```
AVCaptureSession?.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
```

When initialise the session for AVAudioSession for SFSpeechRecognizer, I need to set:

```
AVAudioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, options: [.mixWithOthers, .duckOthers])
```